# OCaml function to check if list is palindrome with floor(n/2) recursive calls and no list allocation

Tags: list, ocaml, palindrome

I have this task on uni, I have researched for a long time, but I cannot find out, how to write this function.
I need it to check if a list is a palindrome, call itself recursively at most floor(n/2) times and not allocate any auxiliary list (so I can use no list constructors).
Any ideas? Tbh, I would like an algorithm than a full solution.

Comment: See the [help/on-topic]: *3. Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.* "I have researched for a long time" is not sufficient.

Comment: Not sure if it's the expected solution, but continuations can surely solve this. (It's basically allocating a linked list, without ever using an explicit Cons)

Comment: Can you use `length`?

Comment: @Bergi no, I cannot. And continuations won't work, cause implicit allocation is not allowed as well.

Comment: Well then the only thing I can imagine is a recursive function that consumes 2 list elements per call, to find the middle of the list.

Comment: Actually it seems more useful to find the *end* of the list. Then you can check for palindromicity on the way out perhaps.

Comment: @Bergi, could You say something more? The only functions like this I can think about allocate new list.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield, I don't understand, how that would help. I think it would allocate a new list.

Comment: I'm wondering how you can use the recursive calls, since the problem doesn't break down easily into a smaller version of the same problem. That's why it's interesting and why people give it out as an assignment. One thing you can do with the recursion is reach the end of the list, which does seem useful. My thinking gets fuzzy after that, sorry :-)

Comment: You can pass down the original list--that doesn't do any allocation. At the end of the list you're interested in the beginning of the list. At the second to the end, you're interested a spot later in the original list. You can look at these things without allocating anything, it seems to me. You just have to traverse the list.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield thanks, it worked! You can see my solution in the answer.

Comment: Have a recursive function that terminates when the list is of length 1 or lower, and compare the first and last element of the list. If not equal, return false, if equal, call this function on the input again without the head and tail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have come up with this and it works:

```
let palindrom l =
let rec aux l0 l1 =
    match (l0, l1) with
    | _,[] -> (true,[])
    | hd :: tl, [x] -> (hd = x, tl)
    | _, hd1 :: tl1 -> let (pal, ll) = aux l0 tl1 in
          match ll with
          | [] -> (pal, [])
          | hd::tl -> (pal && hd1 = hd, tl) in
match l with
[] -> true
| _ -> fst (aux l l)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive helper function that

- on the way in, takes two arguments: a remainder of the list, and a remainder of the list that is twice as far away from the start of the list to be checked.
- reaches its base case in the middle of the list to be checked (when the second list becomes empty, or - in the case of an odd length - has a single element only)
- on the way out, returns an `option` for a list, the remainder that still has to be checked in reverse for equality - or `None` when the palindrome failed to match

Example:

```
// in
hannah hannah
 annah   nnah
  nnah     ah
   nah       
// out
  n <-> nah
 a  <->  ah
h   <->   h
```